# Как отправить фото в Telegram через библиотеку `pytelegrambotapi`?

Tags: python, telegram, telebot

```py
import telebot
from telebot import types
from countryinfo import CountryInfo

country = CountryInfo("Argentina")
bot = telebot.TeleBot('TOKEN')

@bot.message_handler(commands=["start"])
def set_commands(message):
    bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, country.flag())
bot.infinity_polling()
```

`country.flag()` включает в себя вот [эту](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/1a/Flag_of_Argentina.svg) ссылку

Ошибка такая: `A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. Error code: 400. Description: Bad Request: wrong file identifier/HTTP URL specified`

Пробовал через библиотеку requests:

```py
import telebot
from telebot import types
from countryinfo import CountryInfo
import reqests as r

country = CountryInfo("Argentina")
bot = telebot.TeleBot('TOKEN')

r = r.get(country.flag())

@bot.message_handler(commands=["start"])
def set_commands(message):
    bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, r.content)
bot.infinity_polling()
```

Получал ошибку такую: `A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. Error code: 400. Description: Bad Request: IMAGE_PROCESS_FAILED`

Пробовал создать папку, туда добавить картинку, а потом открыть эту картинку и отправить:

```py
import telebot
from telebot import types
from countryinfo import CountryInfo
import requests as r
    
country = CountryInfo("Argentina")
bot = telebot.TeleBot('TOKEN')
f = open("C:/Users/messi/PycharmProjects/Country_bot/image", "wb")
fe = r.get(country.flag())
f.write(fe.content)
f.close()

@bot.message_handler(commands=["start"])
def set_commands(message):
    photo = open("C:/Users/messi/PycharmProjects/Country_bot/image", 'rb')
    bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, photo)
bot.infinity_polling()
```

Но получал ошибку такую: `PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:/Users/messi/PycharmProjects/Country_bot/image'`

Потом пробовал через `os`, но все безуспешно..

Comment: Попробуйте вместо ссылки на изображение использовать само изображение, загруженное в ваш бот

Comment: не совсем понимаю, у меня только ссылка.. вы хотите чтобы я изображение скачал?

Comment: да чтобы бот отправлял картинку не из ссылки, а из файла

Comment: можете код привести к примеру?